# Create a plugin to create a new page in wordpress for each time a record is added into the database

Tags: pages, database, customization

I am new to wordpress and would like to get a way forward for a particular problem.

1. I have a database table A with various columns.
2. For each record in table A a wordpress page needs to be created in the wordpress database.
3. The page should be custom designed.
4. The whole process has to be included in a plugin.
5. The admin uses the plugin to create pages after database is updated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Looks like a whole job description to me.

Comment: This isn't a question, this is a collection of questions, I see at least 4 here, and they should be asked separately

Comment: 1: I have a database with a custom table, how do I generate pages in WordPress from the table rows?

Comment: 2: I have pages i've generated from a table as per Question ABCDlinkgoeshere, I need to apply a custom design to each one, how do I do it?

Comment: 3: I have this code, how do I create a plugin out of it? ( trivial to do )

Comment: wether point number 5 requires a question depends on the answers given to 1 2 and 3, it may not need asking

Comment: It should also be noted that you've deprived yourself of 3 questions worth of reputation by bundling them all into 1, rep you could have used on a bounty in the future. You can still edit your question to be more specific and ask new questions though, so all is not lost!

Answer (score 1):

**Points 1 and 2:**

Use the [`wpdb class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to read the table. Then use [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to create your page.

**Point 3:**

WordPress has a [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) that allows you to define which theme file to use.

**Point 4:**

Read the article on [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and add your code in it.

**Point 5:**

Choose a way to mark which was the last item that was processed, You can for example, save the index of the last article you processed assuming the index increments after each new record. You can even automate the job using [`wp_cron`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron).